# Rendering nested category entities from Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm currently working with a self-referencing entity and i have to build a small list structure (`<ul><li>`) based on that entity. However, the list must take depth into account, so i need to use the parent/children relationship as a base for my renderer. Here's the original entity:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var Category
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="children")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    protected $parent;

    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
     *     targetEntity="Category",
     *     mappedBy="parent",
     *     cascade={"ALL"}
     * )
     */
    protected $children;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId():
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function setParent(Category $parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function setChildren(array $children)
    {
        $this->children = $children;
    }

    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }

    public function addChild(Category $category)
    {
        if (!$this->children->contains($category)) {
            $category->setParent($this);
            $this->children->add($category);
        }
    }

    public function removeChild(Category $category)
    {
        if ($this->children->contains($category)) {
            $this->children->removeElement($category);
        }
    }
}
```

I have implemented a very naive implementation inspired by this: https://wildlyinaccurate.com/simple-nested-sets-in-doctrine-2/

However, this depth-based padding logic doesn't help me with the `<ul><li>` structure. Does anyone recommend any way of rendering self-referencing objects as HTML lists?

Answer (score -2):

Here is how to print out 3 levels of unordered categories list () based tree:

```
<?php $rootCategories = $em->getRepository('Entity\Category')->findBy(['parent' => null]) ?>

// Root categories container
<ul>
<?php foreach ($rootCategories as $rootCategory): ?>
    <li>
        <?= $rootCategory->getName() ?>
        <?php if ($rootCategory->getChildren()): ?>
            // First child categories container
            <ul>
                <?php foreach ($rootCategory->getChildren() as $firstChildCategory): ?>
                    <li>
                        <?= $firstChildCategory->getName() ?>
                        <?php if ($firstChildCategory->getChildren()): ?>
                            // Second child categories container
                            <ul>
                                <?php foreach ($firstChildCategory->getChildren() as $secondChildCategory): ?>
                                    <li><?= $secondChildCategory->getName() ?></li>
                                <?php endforeach ?>
                            </ul>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's hardly scalable. What if there are more than 3 levels?